# Casperjs testing bug with wait

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, wait, casperjs

So i'm working with casperjs and i have this weird problem...

```
casper.test.begin('Login Page Behaviour', function suite(test) {

    login(); //casper.start(URLLOGIN, function() {...}) works fine

    casper.thenOpen(URLBASE, function() {
        test.assert(false, 'message');
    });

    casper.thenOpen(URLBASE, function() {
        test.assert(true, 'message');
    });

    logout(); //casper.thenOpen(URLLOGOUT); works fine too.

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

this code works fine. i have first test that fail and second that works.
But if i add a wait function in first test:

```
casper.thenOpen(URLBASE, function() {
    casper.wait(1000, function() {
       test.assert(false, 'message')
    })
});
```

suddenly the script stop after the first test (if it fail, it doesn't if it pass).

Did I miss something about wait()?

thanks for helping.

Comment: Interesting, this has probably something to do how exceptions are bubbled.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/294e40d58a20238d8da8) I did some tests that should show most of the different use cases and how it behaves.

Comment: Thanks! i will take an instant look at this!

Comment: So only the third one works?
That's weird... i really don't understand why.
but thank you for those tests! i will try to use it.